# Umbraco, create node, list of available node types

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I have document type A with subtypes B, C, D. E and F.
I also have node AA with sub-nodes BB and CC.
I want to create subnode DD under AA and DD must have document type D. 
I have created document type D by my own.
When I create DD I steel see document types B, C, E, F in the list of available option.
What I need to do to create node DD having document type D?

Thank you

- this is U mbraco cms

Comment: What do you mean by _subtype_ ? _Allowed child nodes_, or is A the _master document type_ of B/C/D/E/F ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see all the Document types that are allowed to be used to create nodes under the parent node.

In the "Settings" section, you can restrict which Document types can be used to create nodes under other specific Document types.

For example, go to the Document type A in "Settings > Document types" and click on the "Structure" tab. You can then select the Document types that can be used to create Nodes under any node based upon the A document type.

For future posts like this, I would recommend that you also head over to http://our.umbraco.org.

Answer (score 1):

You can define for every Umbraco *document type* which other *document types* are allowed as child nodes.

For this, you'll need to go to *settings -> Document types*, select your *document type*, go to the *Structure* tab and check the corresponding *Allowed child nodetypes*.

Therefore, every node's *document type* determines the *document types* possible for its child nodes - except for the *Content* root node, any *document type* is allowed there.

[image: umbraco allowed child nodes]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see. I've checked that flags but it didn't take effect. Maybe I should have republished the site or something like that... Nevertheless, thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers